# smtplib import email.utils error

Tags: python, python-2.7, smtplib

I am getting the following error when I am trying to use smtplib in my Python code.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "myemail.py", line 1, in <module>
import smtplib
File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
import email.utils
ImportError: No module named utils
```

Surprisingly, I can include the library when I am working from the Python interpreter directly.

Previously the file was named 'email.py', but according to the answers on stackoverflow regarding similar issues, I changed the name to 'myemail.py'. It still is not working. Kindly help.

Comment: In addition to renaming the email.py to something else, you must also remove the email.pyc

Answer (score 18):

Make sure that there's no `email.py` in the same directory where  the `myemail.py` lives. That prevent importing of the standard library module `email`.

Also make sure there are no remaining `email.pyc` in that directory.

---

If you use your own `email` module, rename it with a different name.

Comment: I wasnt aware of the .pyc file. Thanks :)